# Public Form into SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I'm new to SP and am trying to figure out the most straightforward way to have an external form (no login required) that when filled out, will create a new item in an internal SP list.

So, in practice, a user visits our website, fills out a form and when it is submitted, it creates a new item in an internal list which would start a workflow, etc.

Right now, we have a Wufoo form that is collecting this data for us. It outputs an email each time the form is filled out. The user would have to copy paste from the email into the SP form, field by field. (I can also export the Wufoo data as excel, csv, or tab delimited if that helps, but it's not instance by instance; it's ALL the entries EVER)

It SEEMS like I could use InfoPath for this. I'm not familiar with InfoPath yet though. Would it be possible to embed an InfoPath form onto our current site that would send things to an internal SP list?

The only OTHER thing I can think of is create a separate public SP site for the form and the list that I could probably then access from the internal SP site.

I would LOVE something more straightforward. Embedding a form into our current website would be ideal. I'm perfectly able to teach myself InfoPath, I just want to make sure that it's the route I should take before I spend time and energy on it.

Oh yea. I'm using SPO and the 2013 suite. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try using fillable PDF forms for your website. There is a 3rd party tool - PDF Share Forms, it is not free, but you don't have to learn infopath that is effectively on life support now. It synchronizes form fields with sharepoint columns. I found a webinar on their youtue exactly about public form submission.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MHb6EGcUOQ 
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it might just work! I'll give it a shot.